# Call function inside class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class

I'm trying to create a simple class in PHP, but i've got some trouble with a method call.

```
<?php
include('MySQL.php');

class User {

    var $sql;

    function _construct(){
        // SQL connection

        $this->sql = new MySQL(<<hidden>>, <<hidden>>, <<hidden>>);
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        // TODO
    }
}
?>
```

At the `//TODO` section, i want to do a call like `$this->sql->select('users')`, but it won't let me do it. It gives an error and says that sql is a non-object.

Comment: function of object? O.o

Comment: are you sure your sql connection is working ? use some mysqli error catching inside the constructor and see whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "_construct" is missing a _ (you must have two), to it won't get called. Change it to :

```
public function __construct(){
```

It should work. Also remember to make it public.

If it's not called, you $sql variable isn't initialized and is actually a non-object for PHP.

Also, you may precise the visibility of your variable when declaring it, rather than using the deprecated `var` keyword :

```
private $sql;
```

Comment: if no specifier is provided then its always public !!

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't hurt to precise it.

Comment: `var $sql;` is this really valid php? i've never witnessed someone declare variables of a class like that.

Comment: Yes it is, but it's not recommanded use. One should precise `public $sql` or `private $sql` (I think it should be private). Editing my answer to include that.

Comment: good call @blue112 . the more you can fix at once the better